# Can't SSH into RPi over through Wifi router, direct LAN connection works fine

Tags: ssh, ethernet, static-ip, wifi

I am trying to ssh into my pi over a wifi network from my Win10 laptop.
Now I have assigned static ips to both my PC and the pi but whenever I try to ssh into the pi using puTTY, I get the error

> connection timed out.

I can't even ping the pi, while pinging-

> Destination host unreachable.

While at the same time if I directly connect my pi to my pc via a LAN cable I can ssh in without any problems.

What's the problem here? And how do I resolve it?

Comment: Did you make sure you pi can ping the internet?

Comment: @sir_ian yes I can... both on the Pi and my PC

Comment: Your router remembers the two Mac addresses and t gives hem different up addresses.

Comment: @PaulF8080 what exactly is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I was thinking that port 22 is the ssh service. ip:port has :2222. I did use the word "wild" to say I may be way off. Ignore if you like.

Comment: @PaulF8080 I still don't get what you're trying to say buddy

Comment: The 2222 port looked weird to me so I made a stupid guess, sorry.

Comment: @PaulF8080 never mind. I've been making a lot of stupid guesses all my life and, sometimes they're the wisest ones...